# Change variable type in runtime AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

In Java, when u setting data type while declaring variable, JVM determines how much memory has to be allocated,so,once variable is declared and data type is set, u can not change variable type in run time, how does it work in AS3?

Comment: AFAIK, pretty much the same way. You cannot change the type of variables at runtime.

Comment: I don't know about JVM, but allocation is certainly not that simple in AS3. There are many, many ways allocation can happen after a type is declared. You can also leave a variable untyped or use wildcard (`*`) to indicate *any* value can be assigned to it. That said, you can't change the type declaration at runtime.

Comment: Why do you ask? Is there a future issue you're worried about? Seems silly to expect for example: declaring an Integer type then later changing that type to Sound, or randomly change Sound object to a text String. What a mad world that would be, right? The nearest best option is **casting variable types** if possible.

Comment: VC.One i am not sure if this word means what i mean but, why are u insulting me? if u remember my previous posts, i am looking for performance, i dont want to change integer type to sound, but i want to change say, Number type to uint, when i am done with float numbers and dont want to declare new variable(because of memory and clean code) i want to change that Number type to uint, for more performance, does it look silly now?